# Bash: How do you pass in variable?

Tags: mysql, macos, bash

When you run a bash command, how do you pass in options?

Comment: I don't know how to pass in username and password variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask the user for name and password, you can use `read`. For example:

```
printf "Enter name: "
read name

printf "Enter password: "
read -s password
```

Then the inputs will be available as `$name` and `$password` in the script.

Comment: also what do you mean by Then the inputs will be available as $name and $password in the script

Comment: @user3590113 for -s have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read, for your second comment: these are [variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science))

Comment: @user3590113 The `-s` option makes it possible to not display the characters as the user types. This is useful for passwords. For the variables, I meant that the input will be stored in the `name` and `password` variables that can be accessed as `$name` and `$password` in your code.